# Custom media.phtml for category

Tags: category

I want to use custom media.html for specific category for that I updated below to my category > Custom Layout Update

1: Case A

```
<catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="common/view/default/mediacustom.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and created mediacustom.phtml there but it not works why ??

2: Case B

when i use below code to custom layout update

```
<reference name="product.info.media">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>common/view/default/mediashowgif.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

it show dummy content when  mediashowgif.phtml has simple text/html content

but when i use magento function it show error 
"Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object in "

any help

Comment: are you want for product page ya category page?

Comment: i want same for all product of that category

Comment: i am asking to you are you want to show this on product view page or category view page?

Comment: for product view

Comment: please put code of mediashowgif.phtml

Comment: show the content that you tried inside mediashowgif.phtml

Comment: i just put same content of  mediashowgif.phtml with same style changes nothing else

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a new theme that contains only `catalog/product/view/media.phtml` with the content you need.
Then, in the category edit page, in the tab Custom settings, just select your new theme and set `apply to products` to yes.
This way all the products in you category will use the new media file, and your categories won't get affected.

Answer (score 0):

Saurav.You can  `not update layout of product page from category > Custom Layout Update`.Category custom layout only work on category page layout.

If you want to change product `page change/update  layout from admin then you need to go product>it design tab.`

Most import product page layout id not depend on category layout.

If  you need this create custom handler on product page and then your code basic of this handler

Comment: dear i am able to do so check my case b , it show content of mediashowgif.phtml if it has simple html content, but when i use magento function then only it shows errorr